# Javascript: return promise after promise chaining

Tags: javascript, promise

JavaScript newbie question here: I want to be able to write a function that participates in a promise chain, while doing some promise chaining within it. After the last promise within the chain results, I want to return that promise so that a chain outside the function can continue. Here's my example code. The interesting part is pseudocoded in line 10,

> ```
>     .then(now return this promise);
> ```

what is the correct syntax or methodology for doing this?

```
function setUpConnection() {
  // do whatever
  return client;
}

function doSomeQueries(client) {
  client.query("doSomeSqlHere")
    .then(client.query, "doSomeMoreSqlHere")
    .then(client.query, "do a third query")
    .then(now return this promise);
}

client = setupConnection();
client.connect()
  .then(doSomeQueries(client))
  .then(client.close());
```

Comment: Your `doSomeQueries()` function has to return the promise; currently it returns `undefined`.

Comment: This is pretty easy - just add `return` - i.e. `return client.query("doSomeSqlHere").then(...)`

Comment: Aside from that you'd need to pass a `doSomeQueries` if you expect it to observe "connected" client. `client.connect().then(doSomeQueries)` if `connect` resolves with `client` or `client.connect().then(() => doSomeQueries(client))` if not.

Comment: *"now return this promise"*: an important thing to realise is that you're supposed to return the promise immediately, not when it resolves. `then()` *returns* that promise (i.e. the result of the `then` method call -- not the callback that is passed to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember how I wanted to chain everything when I just started using promises, and how I was shocked by the simplicity of the understanding that it's not required. You can stop chaining and save reference to any point of the chain

```js
function doSomeQueries(client) {
  let promise = client.query("doSomeSqlHere")
    .then(client.query, "doSomeMoreSqlHere")
    .then(client.query, "do a third query")
  return promise; // you can return either Promise<Value> or Value here
}

client = setupConnection();
client.connect()
  .then(doSomeQueries(client))
  .then(client.close());
```

Comment: This only fixes one of the many problems in the code

Comment: Step by step, we will come to a brighter future.@Bergi

Comment: This comment is not true `// you can return either Promise<Value> or Value here`. Effectful (asynchronous) code is contagious, it makes asynchronous everything it touches.  Once you are in a promise-land you stay there.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Agree, it can differ between Promise implementations. But this behaviour is pretty common and handy

Comment: @yevt I don't think I fully understand you. If we assume native js promises there is no way for you to return value synchronously. So you kinda have to return a promise.

Comment: @Bergi do you care to explain?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I hope this example will make my point clearer https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dfrigk?file=index.ts

Comment: @Joymaker You're never passing the proper arguments to `.then(…)`